# NAs in summary of linear model generated from significant genes for continuous response variable identified using SAM

Tags: r, linear-model, genetics, continuous-data, permutation-test

I have a gene expression data-set with log2-transformed expression values (no NAs) for 495 genes for 59 samples for which values of a continuous response variable (r) are also known (no NAs). I want to use leave-one-out cross validation to test if r of the test sample can be predicted from the sample's gene expression.

For this, I intend to use the [samr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/samr/index.html) R package for Significance Analysis of Microarrays to identify significant genes associated with r in the training set of samples. Then, I want to generate a linear model using the significant genes as variables, which will then be used to predict r of the test sample. I have tried the following code to begin with, but when I generate the model and examine it, I see many NAs in the model summary, which makes me suspect that I am doing something wrong.

Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Secondly, I will appreciate any comment on the use of nperms (in SAM) with a value of 100. Is it too low for an expression data-set for 495 genes.

```
# rVals with the r values is read as a vector from a row of a table for phenotypic data read from a tab-delimited file with sample-names as column names and phenotype features as row-names
# geneVals is the log2-transformed gene expression data-set read as a matrix from a tab-delimited file with sample-names as column names and gene-names as row-names

# Perform SAM with FDR of 5% and obtain list of significant genes

sam <- SAM(x=geneVals, y=rVals, resp.type=c("Quantitative"),
testStatistic=c("standard"), regression.method=c("standard"), logged2=TRUE, 
fdr.output=0.05, eigengene.number=1, knn.neighbors=10, nperms=100, 
genenames=as.vector(rownames(geneVals)))

sigGenes <- rbind(sam$siggenes.table$genes.up, sam$siggenes.table$genes.lo)

# Generate linear model
toModel <- data.frame(t(rbind(rVals, geneVals)), check.names=FALSE)
myModel <- lm(toModel[c('r', sigGenes[,c("Gene ID")])])

# Examine model
summary(myModel)

...output...

Call:
lm(formula = toModel[c("rVals", sigGenes[, c("Gene ID")])])

Residuals:
ALL 59 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (58 not defined because of singularities)
           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -18.29363         NA      NA       NA
`let-7e`       -1.70545         NA      NA       NA
`miR-125a-5p`   2.43177         NA      NA       NA
`miR-151-5p`    2.67439         NA      NA       NA
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can now see that the 'NA' issue arises if during model generation the number of variables is more than the number of samples.

Comment: If this reasonably solves your problem you can consider accepting the answer to your own question.

Comment: This appears to be the problem in your case. NAs can also arise when the design matrix is exactly singular (i.e. if you have exact collinearity).